# JSXGraph: use of boundingbox size inside a for loop

Tags: bounding-box, jsxgraph

I would like to display only part of a sequence, depending on the boundingbox values. So consider the following JSXGraph script:

```
    var board = JXG.JSXGraph.initBoard('BOX-jsx_suite_TEST', {boundingbox: [-2, 3, 4, -3],
        keepaspectratio: false});
    // Get the left and right bounds of the bounding box:
    var min=function(){return  board.getBoundingBox()[0];};
    var max=function(){return  board.getBoundingBox()[2];};
    // ... display them:
    var test=board.create('text',[
            function(){return min()+1},
            1,
            function(){return "MIN: "+min()+",  MAX: "+max()}
    ]);
    // ... and plot a function whose domain depends on them:
    var graph=board.create('functiongraph',[
       function(t){return Math.sin(t)},
       function(){return min()+1},
       function(){return max()-1}
    ]);

    // Now, similar but with a for loop:
    for(var i = -1; i < 4; i++) {
    board.create('point',[i, Math.sin(i)], {name:''});
    }
```

Dragging with `SHIFT+MOUSE`, the domain of the graph is changed according to the values of `min()` and `max()`. But why can't I do something similar with the range of the `for` loop? Meaning: why can't I replace `i<4` by `i<function(){return max()-1}`? It seems that everything I put inside this loop ignores the updates with dragging, sliders, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question! In your code, the defining functions of your curve call your function `min()`. This is done during every update of the board. So, whenever the curve is redrawn, the function `min()` is evaluated.

In contrast, the `for`-loop is executed only once, namely in the beginning when the  page is loaded. The points are "free points", set with some initial coordinates. In particular, they do not depend on any other element.

The solution is to create the points with functions as coordinates and these functions also call `min()`. Here is an example (see it live at https://jsfiddle.net/09ykbpat/):

```
// Get the left and right bounds of the bounding box:
var min=function(){return  board.getBoundingBox()[0];};
var max=function(){return  board.getBoundingBox()[2];};
// ... display them:
var test=board.create('text',[
        function(){return min()+1},
        1,
        function(){return "MIN: "+min()+",  MAX: "+max()}
]);
// ... and plot a function whose domain depends on them:
var graph=board.create('functiongraph',[
   function(t){return Math.sin(t)},
   function(){return min()+1},
   function(){return max()-1}
]);

// Now, similar but with a for loop:

for(let i = 4; i < 8; i++) {
        board.create('point', [
        function() { return min() + i; }, 
        function() { return Math.sin(min() + i); }
      ], {name:''});
}
```

Please, note the definition of the variable `i` with `let`. If we would define it with `var`, `i` would be handled as global variable inside of these functions and not just supplying its value during the for loop (*closures* situation!).

Comment: Great, thanks! (I changed `function() { return min() + i; }` into `function() {return Math.round(min())+i;}`, to make sure the points are where they should be.) But my aim was to obtain something that works whatever change is done, like dragging OR zooming. And again, when I zoom on your board, the domain of the function scales properly, but the sequence, of course, contains only four points (corresponding to i=4,5,6,7). So there, I would really need to use `max()` inside the range of the loop.